# Strange result after normalize EigenValues of matrix

Tags: bugs, singularity

I'm trying to get SVD of matrix. but when I multiply matrix, I couldn't get the same matrix. I use wolfram to see decomposition and see what matrix named by "V" have some diference idk why. Here's my code :

```
m={{1,0,1,0,0,0,0},{9,6,8,4,6,6,3}, {10,6,9,4,6,6,3}}
mt = Transpose[m]
a = mt.m
vectors = Eigenvectors[a]
V = Transpose[Normalize /@ vectors]
a1 = m.mt
vectors1 = Eigenvectors[a1]
U = Normalize /@ vectors1
ev = Eigenvalues[a1] 
e = Table[If[i==j,Sqrt[ev[[i]]],0], {i, 3}, {j, 7}] 
{u, \[Sigma], v} =N@ SingularValueDecomposition[m]
```

after what I print my result and result of inbuilt svd function and compare it. How can we see, I should transpose U matrix to get same result with inbuilt, buuuuut V matrix has got a lot of diferents anyone has ideas why?
[image]

[image: My result of SVD]

[image: Inbuilt result of SVD]

Comment: I may not understand fully, but if you have repeated eigenvalues then the corresponding eigenspace can have multiple equivalent sets of basis vectors

Comment: yes, you are right, there can be several eigenvectors

Answer (score 2):

Look at the eigenvalues of "a":

[image]

You see that only the first 2 eigenvalues are different from zero. And there are 4 eigenvalues of zero. This means there is a subspace of dimension 4 that are all eigenvectors to the eigenvalue zero. Therefore, there are an infinity of orthonormal bases for this subspace. This explaines the differences in:

[image]

[image]

Further, look at:

[image]

and

[image]

The second one is identical to the first one with negated sign. Now consider that an eigenvector is only unique up to its sign and magnitude.

Comment: I added some pictures of multiplying matrices. And I still got the wrong answer

Comment: As I already mentioned, eigenvectors are only unique up to sign and magnitude. Therefore, for "V" you need to use the same base vectors as for "v". MMA does not automatically give you the corresponding  base vectors. That is, you must change the sign of the second column in "V"

Comment: Thanks, but why does it happen that if I multiply the 2 vector in the matrix by -1, then the answer converges?

Comment: Then you are using the same basis vectors.